# xquery (.xq) files editor with syntax highlighting in eclipse photon

Tags: eclipse, xquery, eclipse-photon, dltk

Are there any plug-ins that enables syntax highlighting and editing for xquery files in eclipse jee-photon. Something like [XQDT](https://wiki.eclipse.org/XQDT/Installation). This is now replaced by [Dynamic Languages Toolkit](https://projects.eclipse.org/projects/technology.dltk), but even with that installed there is no syntax highlighting for xquery files.